# When do you apply the modulus function to an equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I was just hoping to get some clarification here.

Given the ODE: $$(y'+1)^3 = 27(x+y)^2$$when resolved it becomes $$y' = 3|x+y|^{2/3}-1$$I don't get why the $x+y$ is in a modulus after cube rooting. Is this just something you do when rooting an expression, if so why?

Comment: Please use mathjax to write mathematical formulas. Notice that $(x)^2 = |x|^2$, so you are not really putting a new modulus. But $(x)^{2/3}$ is a less clearly defined notation.

Comment: It is somewhat less of a hassle to define $a^b$ when $a>0$, namely as $\exp(b\ln a)$.